# How to Reset Current Branch to Here in Vs 2019?

Tags: git, visual-studio

In Android Studio, I can *Reset Current Branch to Here* when I use GitHub in a project, you can see Image 1.

But in Vs 2019, I can't find the same function, you can see Image 2, how can I do *Reset Current Branch to Here* in Vs 2019?

**Image 1**
[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Comment: In `gitk` you can right click and select "Reset <the_branch_name> branch to here" (you have gitk installed, it is part of the git for windows package).

Comment: Git is not GitHub...

Comment: Use the "Reset" menu item in VS, it's right under the red box you drew - you need to choose between `--mixed` or `--hard`. I assume Android Studio's "Reset to here" does a `--mixed` or `--soft` reset to avoid unintentional data-loss.

Comment: @HelloCW Could you checkout my proposed solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gui implementations of git features vary a lot between different IDEs. There are many IDEs where features such as reset are not implemented.

I found reset in VS 2019 via "Git repository" -> right click on any commit. See [image: this screenshot].

I came here via "Team Explorer - Home" -> "Git repository", but I think you can directly open "Git repository". It does say "reset current branch to here", but I double checked, it does what you want.

As suggested in comments, you can always use `gitk` where you can right click on any commit to have the same feature. Another great alternative is `git bash` where you can unleash full power of git. In your case `git reset --hard/soft`. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset for details.